# How to covert and print the void pointer array of structure member?

Tags: c, data-structures

As for learning I was creating the library of data structure there I create the structure of stack and added the void pointer use for array and when I m trying to access the value of void pointer array is throw the `invalid conversion of data type error`. Can anyone tell me where I m doing wrong?

```
typedef struct
{
    size_t size;
    size_t top;
    void *st_base;
} stack_t;

dsa_err_t stack_init(stack_t *stack, uint32_t size)
{
    DSA_CHECK_ARG(stack);

    stack->st_base = (int32_t *)calloc((size_t)size, sizeof(int32_t));
    if (!(stack->st_base))
    {
        return DSA_NO_MEM;
    }
    stack->top = 0;
    stack->size = size;
    return DSA_OK;
}
dsa_err_t stack_push(stack_t *stack, int32_t item)
{
DSA_CHECK_ARG(stack && stack->st_base);

if (stack->top >= (stack->size - 1))
{
    return DSA_FAIL;
}

stack->st_base[(stack->top)++] = item; ---> EXPRESSION MUST BE MODIFIABLE VALUE ERROR
return DSA_OK;
}

dsa_err_t stack_pop(stack_t *stack, int32_t *item)
{
DSA_CHECK_ARG(stack && stack->st_base);

if (stack_is_empty(stack) || stack->top > (stack->size - 1))
{
    return DSA_FAIL;
}
*item = (int32_t)stack->st_base[stack->top - 1]; ---> INVALID TYPE OF CONVERSION ERROR
stack->st_base[stack->top--] = 0;
return DSA_OK;
}
```

Comment: Why do you use `void *st_base` in your structure while `...init`, `...push` and `...pop` want to use it as an `int32_t *`? If you plan to make your stack implementation independent from a data type you would need to specify the element size as an additional argument for `stack_init` and you could use `memcpy` to copy data between your stack array and a `void *` input/output pointer.

Comment: @Bodo Thanks for the input. I was implemented the stack independent of data type. but I got some issue with void pointer to so i used the int32_t data type. Now I again trying to implement as independent data type. Some issue in still getting in stack pop function. Its giving the  same deferenece void pointer error. code -> `item = &stack->st_base[stack->top - 1];`

Comment: You accepted the answer, so your original question seems to be answered. The answer contains two code snippets, one for `...push` and one for `...pop`. If the answer is not clear for you, write a comment to the answer asking for clarification. If you have a related question that came up while you continued the work on your program, write a new question, maybe with a reference to this one.

Answer (score 3):

A `void *` is an incomplete type and therefore can't be dereferenced (and array indexing is a form of dereferencing).  You need to convert it to a usable pointer type first.

```
((int32_t *)stack->st_base)[(stack->top)++] = item;
...
*item = ((int32_t *)stack->st_base)[stack->top - 1];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was writng function for stack_pop there I m passing void pointer as parameter `dsa_err_t stack_pop(stack_t *stack, void *item)
{
    DSA_CHECK_ARG(stack && stack->st_base);

    if (stack_is_empty(stack) || stack->top > (stack->size - 1))
    {
        return DSA_FAIL;
    }
    item = &stack->st_base[stack->top];
    memset(&stack->st_base[stack->top], 0, 1);
    stack->top--;

    return DSA_OK;
}` but I m not getting right value there. I m getting dummy values. Can I retrive value without converting any data type.